# Run and Gun game with bird creature as the protagonist

Tags: identify-this-game

I faintly remember playing a 16 bit game as a kid, which is some sort of hardcore run and gun game. I don't remember if it was on a Sega Genesis or a Super Nintendo.

- You take control of some bird / human hybrid, who can switch between four weapons, which the protagonist shoots from his hands.
- There is some weird counter move where you can make health appear, but I don't remember how it works.
- You can float in place.
- You have a short range teleport move that can go only horizontally. Sometimes you turn into a fireball, but I'm not sure when that occurs.
- There were less regular enemy encounters and more bosses. In fact, the game was full with bosses, with not that many actual levels.

Comment: I'd suggest Ranger X for the Sega, but I don't remember a teleport. Do you have any recollection of art style or setting?

Comment: @Tommy Hm... well, I think it was set in the future? It certainly looked like a futuristic setting. I don't remember the art style as much, but I remember the sprites of the characters were quite big for this kind of game (especially the character you control), compared to Gunstar Heroes at least.

Comment: Then maybe take a look at Ranger X just in case I've forgotten parts of it — I've played it only very casually: https://youtu.be/RW39b9_cVws?t=132 will skip straight to some gameplay.

Comment: @Tommy Damn, I forgot to mention, I already looked it up and no, that's not the game I was looking for. Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at [this article](https://8bitbudgies.com/2018/03/12/top-10-retro-video-games-featuring-birds/) and found a few games similar to what you're describing, perhaps it's worth glancing at those in case this answer isn't what you're looking for.

The closest match I could find is:

> **The NewZealand Story**

This is a **sidescrolling run-and-gun** released in 1988. It has a **bird-human hybrid protagonist**, a flightless humanoid kiwi named Tiki, and features **four weapons** which the protagonist **shoots from his hands**: arrows, bombs, lasers and fireballs. However, it was not released on the SNES as far as I can tell, and it doesn't seem to have the floating in place or counter move you're describing. [Here's some gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YViBVvjn5K4).

[image]

The next best thing I found after a bit more searching is:

> **Alien Soldier**

A **sidescrolling run-and-gun** that also has a **bird-human hybrid protagonist,** Epsilon-Eagle. The eagle has a double jump, uses six different weapons, and can **hover in the air.** He also **shoots fireballs from his hands.** However, it was only released for the Sega Mega Drive. [Here's some gameplay.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA03WAjg6ic)

[image]

Are either of these what you're looking for?

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Thanks for your contributions so far; you've only been around for an hour and already have almost enough reputation to start nagging moderators! If you're looking for somewhere to contribute other than improving questions and writing excellent answers, one of the more boring tasks is [writing tag wikis](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags?page=4&tab=popular) that explain how tags are to be used ([here's an example](/tags/ms-dos/info)); if you spot anything that looks off (e.g. an [tag:abstract-art] tag) you can bring it up on [meta]. :-)

Comment: New Zealand Story did come out for the Mega Drive though. It's a unique port, being a conversion of the arcade game before it was finished and therefore having quite different level layouts. It was also much more widely available for the Master System (though it isn't 60Hz compatible, so presumably not in Brazil) — perhaps a Powerbase Converter has scrambled the memory?

Comment: ALIEN SOLDIER, THANK YOU!!! Finally, it's been bothering me for such a long time, that's the game I was looking for. Btw, you have six different weapons, but you can only use four during gameplay, so I wasn't wrong on that exactly.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! :) I love retro games like these.